# What happened to seeing deleted Q&As?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, privileges, deleted-questions

In the past I could see deleted posts, both questions and answers, because I had reached a certain (pretty low, actually) threshold of points. Now I can't see any of them anymore. Did the threshold get raised? Are only moderators allowed to see these now? Are they now completely removed and deleted from SE's servers? (I'm not sure this is a bug, but I needed an appropriate tag.)

Comment: FYI, if your issue is along the lines of "please explain what's going on here," but you don't seriously suspect a malfunction, the tag to start with is [meta-tag:support].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the rep requirements for privileges went up when we launched out of beta. The current list is at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation, and you can see your own progress against the various milestones at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges.

The ability to view deleted posts comes with the "[Moderator Tools](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)" privilege, which now kicks in at 10000 reputation points. You're 81% of the way there!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm dismayed, though, to see that I'm not trusted. :(

Comment: @SethJ <Fatherly voice>You have lost your trust</Fatherly voice>

Comment: @SethJ, yeah, me too. :-)