# Comments on Q/As causing changes on main page

Tags: support, comments

Since when do comments on questions and answers show up on the main page?  I don't mean that they can be read there, but that the question is bumped up on the main page, and that the last activity noted on the right side below the title is the comment (or, rather, the time of the comment and the name and rep score of the commenter - "3 h ago  JoeYodeya 1205", for example).

Comment: Can you point to an example?

Answer (score 8):

What you're seeing may be an instance of an answer that was converted by a mod into a comment. The post was bumped when the user posted the answer, but all you see now is the comment, as the answer in its original form was deleted and [is invisible](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/what-happened-to-seeing-deleted-qas) to users with less than 10K rep.

Comment: Urgh, still not used to not seeing deleted posts. Thanks!

Comment: @SethJ Mazel Tov on your recent 10K! I just noticed.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I take it back. I just saw a deleted answer on an old question. But I still thank you (I don't take that part back).

Comment: @SethJ Here are the tools. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=stats&daterange=today